# round carbon date to closest previous 6 hour mark

Tags: javascript, momentjs, php-carbon

i have an application that executes a cron job every 6 hours:

00:00, 06:00, 12:00, 18:00

How do i round the current time to the lowest matching hour of the above?

So if its 13:05 now, it should return 12:00

edit: i meant in javascript, not in php. updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function and it is without moment.js

```
function getRoundedTime(){
  var d = new Date();
  var now = d.getHours();
  if(now > 6){
    var roundedTime = now - (now % 6);
    var stringTime = roundedTime.toString().concat(":00");
    return stringTime;
  }
  if(now < 6){
    return "00:00";
  }
  if(now % 6 === 0) {
    return "0" + now.toString().concat(":00");
  }
}

getRoundedTime();
```

Or if you want moment.js then import moment and inside function declare now like this `var now = moment().hour();`